# How do I add a folder to sync.?

Tags: 12.10, ubuntu-one, sync

I've just recently installed U1 on Ubuntu 12.04LTS and I've chosen 4 folders to synchronise with U1.  The system itself add another 2 = Ubuntu One and Thunderbird Attachments.

But I want to add a few more of my own folders, and that seems not to be possible.

If I go to Nautilus, right-click on a folder, choose UbuntuOne -- Synchronise this folder ... then nothing happens.

Why?

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192467/frozen-dialogue-window-in-ubuntu-one

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Ubuntu One is **connected**, on the top right.

[image: Connect Ubuntu One]

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Unfortunately - nothing new, since my U.One states: "Sync'ing underway and [Disconnect]"  (stated in Danish ... my translation)

As something new though - my U1 starts to crash when I try anything like adding a new file/folder or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what I did, but after some complaining, a few U1-crashes, and a few turning off and on of the connect-button in U1 ... it suddenly works fine!

Thanks for your help and patience :-)

Comment: I was just searching for this bug! :D

Answer (score 0):

Generally it takes few seconds for file sync to start. You will get a notification saying that the file sync has started.
Also, to check whether the sync process has started or not, open Ubuntu One (using Dash or otherwise). If the sync failed to start, then you can add it from the option *Add a Folder from this computer*.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the folder via Ubuntu One application?

Start Ubuntu One via dash, and under "Folders" tab you shuold see "My personal folders". All folders, which are synchronized with your ubuntu one account should be listed there. If they are not, try to add them - click on Add a folder from this computer.